# Не видит Jquery в React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

react не видит обычных js библиотек. Никто не знает как просто без глубокого изучения webpack подключить js-библиотеку к react?

Comment: Просто установка через npm не подходит, он на нее жалуется.

Comment: Во-первых, как всегда, а во-вторых, не видит - и хорошо. Ну и наконец, реакт - сам обычная библиотека.

Comment: Реакт использует ecma6, все либы на js. Он дико жалуется на них в неявных местах + туда нельзя просто импортировать недостающую библиотеку что бы не было undefined.

Comment: Так не надо импортировать - просто используй и всё.

Comment: Нужен код. У меня есть ощущение того что Вы слабо понимаете чего делаете, в частности не понимаете где кончается реакт и начинается модульная система

Comment: Просто импортирую jquery.cookie из nodejs, он жалуется на то, что там нет jquery ибо он не import, так как это не ecma6, a обычный js. Код: import 'jquery.cookie' + еще хочу импортировать particles.js (у npm версии нет поддержки конфигов), тут уже вылезают толпы undefined. В обычном js все норм

Comment: jquery это для клиента, а не для сервера, если только вы не эмулируете работу браузера в node

Answer (score 1):

Вариант 1. Просто подключить `jQuery` как библиотеку с сервера или с CDN:

```
<script src="https://my.server.ru/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Пример работы `jQuery` и `React`:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  onClick = () => {
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
  };
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button 
          type="button"
          className="btn btn-primary"
          onClick={this.onClick}
        >Open modal</button>
        
        <div id="myModal" className="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
          <div className="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div className="modal-content">
              <div className="modal-header">
                <button type="button" className="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
                <h4 className="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
              </div>
              <div className="modal-body">
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
              </div>
              <div className="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" className="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(
  <App/>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous"><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="container">
<div id="root"></div>
</div>
```

Вариант 2. Если нужно включить `jQuery` в общий бандл (вебпаком или др.):

```
$ npm -i jquery --save
```

в app.js:

```
let $ = require('jquery');
window.$ = window.jQuery = $;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
npm i create-react-app -g
create-react-app <project_name>
```

Все будет в коробке, и *css* тоже будет работать.